# Are there guidelines and/or standards for creating desktop shortcuts during installation?

Tags: windows, installation, desktop, icons

Personally I hate auto-created desktop shortcut icons, but some folks seem to think that unless your installer clutters up your desktop, it hasn't worked correctly!

**Are there definite guidelines for this** (for Windows?)

(Having a "Leave clutter on my desktop?" checkbox in the installer is one option, but to my mind, that's just put MORE clutter into the installer...)

Comment: totally agree with you! Don't clutter my desktop - ASK ME

Comment: I edited to try and make this more objective. Since the accepted answer gives nice factual information about documented standards / guidelines, this seemed pretty reasonable.

Comment: Insisting on using the opinionated term "clutter" in every aspect of this "question" firmly keeps this in an "opinionated" category.  Updating it to use the proper terms is necessary to consider it as an objective, fact finding question in good faith.

Comment: @SherylHohman Read the question title and the bold bit. It's clear this question is specifically NOT seeking opinionated answers, and expressing an opinion in a question shouldn't be a problem. At least, it wasn't ten years ago. Also check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/winenv-desktop

> **If your users are very likely to use your program frequently, provide an option during setup to put a program shortcut on the desktop.** Most programs won't be used frequently enough to warrant offering this option.
>
> **Present the option unselected by default.** Requiring users to select the option is important because once undesired icons are on the desktop, many users are reluctant to remove them. This can lead to unnecessary desktop clutter.
>
> **If users select the option, provide only a single program shortcut.** If your product consists of multiple programs, provide a shortcut only to the main program.
>
> **Put only program shortcuts on the desktop.** Don't put the actual program or other types of files.

Comment: If only more applications paid more attention to this (and also offered selection of where you want the program shortcuts in the start menu)...  It really annoys me that Acrobat Reader adds its shortcuts back to the Desktop and the root of the Start Menu every time it installs an security update.

Comment: Thanks - a great link to some freshly baked Windows 7 guidelines!

Comment: In 2018 (almost 2019!) is this still the prevailing advice? I ask because our installer is often blocked from creating a desktop icon by Windows 10's anti-virus software.

Answer (score 2):

My take is this: the installer must ask me if I want a desktop icon - to which I can reply yes or no.

Any app that just blindly and without asking installs its icon on my desktop is a bad installation in my opinion.

Ask for permission - if I deem your app important enough to me personally, I might say yes (but most likely I won't). Give your users a choice - don't just assume since it's your app, it's so darn important to everyone that everyone will want to clutter up their desktop with your program icon.

The same goes for the installation directory - unless you have a very good technical reason why you can't install anywhere, allow me to change the program's installation target directory. Not everyone is a big fan of the "c:\program files" folder hierarchy (I'm not, for one - I like to keep my apps in C:\bin for instance).

So in general: any decent installer should ASK the user installing for these things and present sensible defaults - but always give me the option to change the settings to my liking (to my standards).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any meaningful guidelines, other than your conscience. As a programmer, I sympathize: I don't want icons on my desktop, either :-) However, having watched non-technical family members struggle with installing software and then trying to run it, I think it's worth noting that

1) There are more non-techies than techies
2) Techies can cope with checkboxes on installers

Based on that, I usually go for having a checkbox on the installer for creating icons, which defaults to on. I don't mind anything other than the "always create icons" approach. (I'm looking at you, Adobe.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on what you see your client doing with the app, the level of the client's expertise with computers and how frequently you see him using it.

1. If the client is not very well versed with computers he would prefer to have the icon on the desktop where he can access it. If you target market is experienced users you don't need to bother because he can make the icon himself if he wants it.
2. If the application is for daily frequent use like a web browser the client would want it on his desktop for quick access.

Finally the decision rests on you. If you're being obnoxious you can create 4 icons on the desktop (I've seen apps that do that).

I don't think asking for permission is a bad idea. After all the installation needs to be done only once and it's just one checkbox to tick.

Answer (score 0):

I've no particular love for desktop (or quick launch) shortcut icons either, but I think that you should still give your users the option in the installer to install neither, one or both of these shortcuts.

Depending on how computer literate your users are (if it's possible to determine this) you can default the two options to either enabled or disabled accordingly.